# Requests don't return all of the information

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get data from the products on this site: https://www.blocket.se/annonser/hela_sverige?q=dunjacka

When I try to scrape the website using beautifulsoup and requests I only recieve parts of the html code on the website. The sections containing the data about the products is not extracted.

My code is this, it should return the price of all products on the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

variable = input("What word would you like to search: ")
url = "https://www.blocket.se/annonser/hela_sverige?q=" + variable
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="__next")

product_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="MediumLayout__BodyWrapper-sc-q6qal1-2 gYhFaY")

print(product_elements)

for product_element in product_elements:
    price_element = product_element.find_all("div", class_="Price__StyledPrice-sc-1v2maoc-1 hAKWLn")

    print(price_element.text)
```

print(price_element.text) should return the price in text format.

print(product_elements) returns all extracted data, the product data is missing from the extracted data which is why I get no return from print(price_element).

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via Javascript. You can simulate it via `requests`/`json` modules:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://api.blocket.se/search_bff/v2/content"

params = {
    "lim": "40",
    "q": "dunjacka",
    "st": "s",
    "status": "active",
    "include": ["placements", "extend_with_shipping"],
    "gl": "3",
}

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer bc2bfd5794465693e5e40098c30dafb5d3f01446"}

data = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some sample data:
for d in data["data"]:
    print(
        "{:<55} {}".format(d["subject"], d.get("price", {}).get("value", "N/A"))
    )
```

Prints:

```
Dunjacka i fint skick stl ca 155-165 cm.                1500
Peak Performance vinterjacka                            2000
Dunjacka, storlek XXL                                   150
Parajumpers dunjacka vår/höst                           900
Dunjackor                                               500
Ny vinterjacka stl 134                                  250
HOPE dunjacka                                           600
Patagonia dunjacka mörkblå small                        800
Acne dunjacka                                           2500
Jacka / kappa svart H&M 146 cl                          150
Dunjacka Jack Wolfskin 152                              150
vinterjackor och regnrock                               90
Svart Kenzo vinter/dunjacka                             1900
Dunjacka                                                450
Dunjacka från Polo Ralph Lauren, stl 160                500
Polo Sport, Ralph Lauren dunjacka (strl medium herr)    600
Peak Performance dunjacka i fint skick.                 2200
Parajumpers Right Hand NY storlek Medium                5200
Sail Racing Dunjacka                                    1000
Fjällräven dunjacka - M - Mörkblå                       5000
LEMPELIUS JACKA DOWN COAT                               2900
Moncler dunjacka                                        999
Colmar jacka medium dam röd vinterjacka dunjacka        650
Dunjacka barn The North Face                            300
Vinterjacka Cedrico                                     4900
Svart dunjacka                                          450
dunjacka herr XL                                        350
Spyder dunjacka                                         700
Dunjacka                                                850
Canada snow sheila jacka i svart - nyskick!             850
North race dunjacka, Polo Ralph Lauren och Gant         250
Ny Fjällräven dunjacka                                  N/A
Blonde No.8 POLAR dunjacka                              850
Bergans of norway Dunjacka                              700
Fjällräven Dunjacka 1974                                700
Peak performance dunjacka                               2000
Lyxig Oscar Jacobson dunjacka                           1100
LINDEBERG DUNJACKA DUN PARKAS DYR NY 5999 KR            1400
Canada Goose Heli Arctic                                3000
Vinson Polo dunjacka                                    300
```

Comment: I can't find the link as a source, and when I try your code I recieve a KeyError. I think it's because the link has changed or because it isn't in the source code of the website.